# Django management command as a package?

Tags: python, django, django-commands

I'm trying to have a directory structure for my custom django-admin commands.

According to the Django tutorial, commands are created as modules under the `management/commands` directory.
e.g.
`management/commands/closepoll.py`

I have many commands so I'm trying to split them into packages. I want to have a package structure, like:
`management/commands/closepoll/closepoll.py`  <-- contains the `Command` class.
`management/commands/closepoll/closepoll_utils.py`
`management/commands/closepoll/__init__.py`

Tried that, but Django does not recognize the command.

Comment: what is your project structure exactly? Screenshot of it would help. Management package should be inside app folder that is added in settings.py under installed apps

Comment: @KarolMilewczyk I've mentioned the relevant parts. Of course, I have a standard Django project structure, with settings.py, and my app is added to the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting

Comment: how about adding utils package on the same level as commands? that would unclutter the commands folder since the option you mentioned seems not to have an easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible since Django only searches the commands directory as we can see from the [source code <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b30c0081d4d8a31ab7dc7f72a4c7099af606ef29/django/core/management/__init__.py#L29-L39):

> ```
> return [
>     name
>     for _, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.iter_modules([command_dir])
>     if not is_pkg and not name.startswith("_")
> ]
> ```

What you can do is that you can have the `Command` class in the "commands" directory and the the other parts of the same can be in a package:

```
managment/
├─ __init__.py
├─ commands/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ closepoll.py
│  ├─ closepoll_utils/
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
```

In case of the above example `closepoll.py` will have the `Command` class and what you had in `closepoll_utils.py` will be in `closepoll_utils/__init__.py`. In fact you can even have the `Command` class in your package and simply import it in `closepoll.py`.